# R Check if multiple variables with the same pattern have the same values

Tags: r

I have some variables in my data frame that show the same pattern, and that should also have the same content. Now I want to check whether all rows show the same values for these variables.  In this example, I want to compare all variables that start with "a" and want to get "True" if they are indeed all the same. How do I do that?

```
 df = data.frame(
  a1 = c(1,2,3), 
  nn22 = c(8,9,3), 
  a2 = c(1,2,3), 
  nn = c(8,9,3), 
  u6 = c(8,4,3), 
  o8 = c(3,9,1), 
  a3 = c(1,2,3), 
  a4 = c(1,2,3), 
  a5 = c(1,2,3), 
  a6 = c(1,2,3), 
  b= c(2,2,2))
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We could split the data into a `list` of `data.frame` based on the prefix names and then use `==` by comparing the first column with all other columns after looping over the `list` with `sapply`.  Wrap with `all` to check if we have all TRUEs

```
sapply(split.default(df, sub("\\d+$", "", names(df))), function(x) all(x[,1] == x))
#    a    b   nn    o    u 
#TRUE TRUE TRUE TRUE TRUE
```

---

If we need only to compare 'a' columns

```
dfa <- df[startsWith(names(df), 'a')]
all(dfa == dfa[,1])
#[1] TRUE
```

Comment: Thanks, and how do you only compare variables that start with "a"?